# .htaccess как "игнорировать" несуществующую часть (папку c файлом - их нет) url?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Суть в том, что был перенесён сайт, но нужно сохранить старые ссылки. Раньше мультиязычность была организована влоб - в каждой папке свой язык, пример (fr язык):

```
/french/index.php
/french/about.php
// и другие файлы в папке french, english, etc...
```

Теперь мультиязычность сделана отдельным модулем, независимым от расположения файлов. Соответственно, были убраны все лишние файлы и папки.

Но появилась и проблема - как сделать чтобы по уже не существующим старым ссылкам открывались файлы с корня?
примеры

```
// ссылка в браузере:
/french/index.php
// -> файл /index.php

// ссылка в браузере:
/french/about.php
// -> файл /about.php
```

Самый простой не работающий вариант выглядел так:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.php $2.php?lng=$1 [L]
```

Пробовал уже много чего, пока так и не приблизился к решению.

Comment: с самими правилами скорее всего проблем нет, во всяком случае на приведенных примерах, можете проверить тут https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/, думаю вопрос может быть в другом, вплоть до того а применяется ли вообще хоть какие-то правила из этого файла, или на каком уровне от корня этот файл, ну или что-то еще подобного или иного рода

Comment: @DaniilLoban есть и другие правила, они работают, проблема именно в этом, и файлы все в корне

Comment: добавил ответ с добавлением флага R если не поможет, то возможно до этого правила просто не доходит (можно попробовать поднять выше) либо понадобятся доп детали для воспроизведения

Comment: @DaniilLoban удалил все остальные, не помогло. Какие именно детали нужны? Я даже не знаю что на это влиять может

Comment: думаю стоит посмотреть логи, возможно там что-то всплывет, вообще как минимум мне бы хотелось понять как выглядит ошибка, как я могу ее воспроизвести, хочется четко понять за каким именно зайцем мы гоняемся

Comment: @DaniilLoban мой косяк. По глупости забыл упомянуть важную часть и не туда смотрел. Используется nginx c обратным прокси apache2, скорее всего тут собака зарыта

Comment: с бОльшей вероятностью да, попробуйте `L` заменить на `last` (вариант nginx) и добавьте что ли схему в вопрос как у Вас и что

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Настроил на своем сервере таким образом (добавил флаг R):

```
# Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; img-src https: data:;"

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.php /$2.php?lng=$1 [R,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /custom-404.php
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Использование флага [R] вызывает перенаправление HTTP в браузер. Если
> указан полный URL-адрес (то есть включающий http://имя_сервера/), то
> будет выполнено перенаправление на это место. В противном случае
> текущий протокол, имя сервера и номер порта будут использоваться для
> создания URL-адреса, отправляемого с перенаправлением.
>
> Можно указать любой действительный код состояния ответа HTTP,
> используя синтаксис [R=305], при этом по умолчанию используется код
> состояния 302, если он не указан. Указанный код состояния не
> обязательно должен быть кодом состояния перенаправления (3xx). Однако
> если код состояния выходит за пределы диапазона перенаправления
> (300–399), то строка замены полностью отбрасывается, а перезапись
> останавливается, как если бы использовалась буква L.
>
> В дополнение к кодам состояния ответа вы также можете указать статус
> перенаправления, используя их символические имена: временный (по
> умолчанию), постоянный или см. другие.
>
> Вы почти всегда будете использовать [R] в сочетании с [L] (то есть
> использовать [R,L]), потому что сам по себе флаг [R] добавляет
> http://thishost[:thisport] к URI. , но затем передает это следующему
> правилу в наборе правил, что часто может приводить к предупреждениям
> «Недопустимый URI в запросе».

Comment: Переадресация не вариант, в том и проблема что нужно ссылки оставить вида /folder/file.ext

Comment: без `R` у меня так и было, файл показывало но путь оставался не тронут

Answer (score 0):

Добавляешь эту строку

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/твой файл\.расширение$
```

Comment: Абсолютно ничего не меняется

Answer (score -1):

попробуй например в `/franch/` закинуть ht* с единственным правилом - `ErrorDocument 404 ../(.*)` а после щупать ссылки френча. мб поможет, но это не точно.

насколько помню, при использовании относительных ссылок в ED* они работают не как redirect а как include.
т.е. загружается URL указанный в правиле, но в строке браузера остается ошибочный

за пределами этой папки данное 404 правило работать конечно не должно, там уже корневой htaccess будет править баллом.

---

еще в качестве временного костыля можно прицепить примитивный js цикл с innerHTML, который будет на лету заменять url в ссылках по регулярке.

---

p.s. в spa-js фреймворках можно подключить роутинг, как впрочем и в ванильном js через history api.
но по части js роутинга я ваще мало что знаю, так что, мне тут подсказать особо нечего.

https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html